# Split array keys by integer

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
array(10) { 
    [1]=> string(10) "Question 1"
    ["1a"]=> string(7) "option1"
    ["1b"]=> string(7) "option2"
    ["1c"]=> string(7) "option3"
    ["1d"]=> string(7) "option4"
    [2]=> string(10) "Question 2"
    ["2a"]=> string(7) "option1"
    ["2b"]=> string(7) "option2"
    ["2c"]=> string(7) "option3"
    ["2d"]=> string(7) "option4"
}
```

I want to split the array and echo the values between `<li>` tags. The problem is that, when I try to loop through the array keys, I cannot figure out how to sort them per integer in the array key and it echoes all elements between separate `<li>` tags instead of **one** for the five values of the keys containing **1**, one for the five values of the keys containing 2, and so on.

This is the php code I'm currently using:

```
$form = array();

    foreach($_POST as $key => $val) {

    $q_answers = array();

    if (is_numeric($key)) {

        $question = trim(htmlspecialchars($val));

    } else if (is_string($key) && !empty($val)) {

        $q_answers[] = '<input type="button" value="'.trim(htmlspecialchars($val)).'" data-skip="0" />';

    }
    $form[] = $question.' '.implode(' ', $q_answers);

}

    $result = '
<ul>
    <li>'.implode('</li>
    <li>', $form).'</li>
</ul>';

}
```

Here's an example of what I am looking for:

Array:

```
Array(10) {
    [1]=> "Question 1"
    [1a]=> "option1"
    [1b]=> "option2"
    [1c]=> "option3"
    [1d]=> "option4"
    [2]=> "Question 2"
    [2a]=> "option1"
    [2b]=> "option2"
    [2c]=> "option3"
    [2d]=> "option4"
}
```

Output:

```
<ul>
    <li>Question 1: option1 option2 option3 option4</li>
    <li>Question 2: option1 option2 option3 option4</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Looks like in your array the keys would always be numeric. Are you sure you want to split by key and not by value ? can you also update your question to add sample output that you want ?

Comment: Array keys must be unique that is not a valid array. Only the last 5 elements will be in your array (2, 2a, 2b, 2c, 2d);

Comment: you mean `array values`, right? your array keys are already numeric.

Comment: Not all my array keys are not numeric, are they? `1a`, `1b`, `1c` etc?

Comment: What I posted above is a `var_dump(array_keys($array))`

Comment: Why not just use a multidimensional array?

Comment: Please put your exact array and also your expected outcome. you are confusing everyone.

Comment: Alright, I posted the full array. The expected outcome is at the bottom of my post.

Comment: Why does you array look like that? What's wrong with multidimensional arrays?

Comment: It's an array submitted by a form, it's `$_POST` that is the array I'm trying to split. Each question and answer option has its own input field resulting in an instance in the `$_POST` array.

Comment: Than name your fields like `<input type="text" name="questions[1][a]"...`.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know you could send multidimensional arrays via HTML, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$array = {};
$options1 = {}
$options2 = {}
$options1[1a] = "option1";
$options1[1b] = "option2";
$options1["Name"] = "Question 1";
$options2[2a] = "option1";
$options2[2b] = "option2";
$options2["Name"] = "Question 2";
$array[1] = $options1;
$array[2] = $options2;
echo("<ul>");
foreach ($array as $option){
echo("<li>" . $option["Name"] . ":");
foreach ($optionas $suboption){
echo(" " . $suboption);
}
echo("</li>");
}
echo("</ul>");
```

You could use functions to fast-build these arrays :)